# File is adding one extra space in each line

Tags: perl

I am trying to add all the elements in array using push . then i stored into another file

but begining of file i am seeing one whitespeace in every thing ..

What is the issue .. any one before face this issue .

```
open FILE , "a.txt"

while (<FILE>)
{

  my $temp =$_;

  push @array ,$temp;

}
close(FILE);

open FILE2, "b.txt";
print FILE2 "@array";
close FILE2;
```

Comment: [Line 17](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?line_17).

Comment: Fixed Line 17 error.. who found this ? Line 17

Comment: Here's a riddle. Only I know the answer, but only you know the question. We're at an impasse! How about you tell me the question and then I'll tell you the answer.  Hint: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you quote an array variable like this: `"@array"` it gets interpolated with spaces. That's where they come from in your output. So do not quote if you do not need or want this sort of interpolation.

Now let's rewrite your program to modern Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie qw(:all);

my @array;
{
    open my $in, '<', 'a.txt';
    @array = <$in>;
}

{
    open my $out, '>', 'b.txt';
    print {$out} @array;
}
```

Comment: You have declared `@array` twice, so one will overshadow the other.

Comment: Fixed. That teaches me to always test run my programs, even if they're just 10 lines. `:-|`

Answer (score 4):

You put quotes around `"@array"`.  That makes it a string interpolation, which for arrays is equivalent to `join($", @array)`.  The default value for `$"` is (guess what?) a space.

Try

```
print FILE2 @array;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`open`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#open) usually takes another argument that specifies whether the file is opened for input or for output (or for both or for some other special case). You have omitted this argument, and so by default `FILE2` is an input filehandle.

You wanted to say

```
open FILE2, '>', "b.txt"
```

If you put the line

```
use warnings;
```

at the beginning of every Perl script, the interpreter will catch many issues like this for you.

Comment: and for clarity, it would also be better to say `open FILE1, '<', "a.txt"`